# How can I stop a loop from within another loop?

Tags: java, loops, break

So, I am running a for Loop from within a while-Loop. And if my if() finds something(from within the for-loop), it should stop both the for and while-loop.
Btw, this is Java.
Here my Code:

```
while(!(objecFound)){
            for(int i = 0; i <= currObsTile.length; i++){
                if(currObsTile[i].tile == endTile){
                    //If this is true, it needs to stop the while loop
                }
            }
        }
```

Thanks

Comment: Add another condition to the for loop to check if it should stop, probably `objecFound` like the outer has. Or `break` out of it

Comment: return; is a good way, however I think this kicks you out of the whole method.

Comment: In your case, `objecFound = true`

Answer (score -1):

You can solve this with a Java label:

```
    OuterLoop:
    while(!(objecFound)){
        for(int i = 0; i <= currObsTile.length; i++){
            if(currObsTile[i].tile == endTile){
                //If this is true, it needs to stop the while loop
                break OuterLoop;
            }
        }
    }
```